# Check if n number of checkboxs are not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following HTML elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dog_pop_123">
<input type="checkbox" id="cat_pop_123">
<input type="checkbox" id="parrot_pop_123">
```

I want to check that, if the three of the checkboxes are not checked, I need to return false.  However, I need to take into account that the third checkbox might not exist.

Right now I have this:

```
var id = 123;

if ( !$('#dog_pop_'+id+':checked').length
    && !$('#cat_pop_'+id+':checked').length
    && !$('#parrot_pop_'+id+':checked').length ) {
  return false;
}
```

However, if the last input doesn't exist, and the first two do exist and are checked, this would return false, and it should not.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You talk about an HTML structure, but I don't see any. If you post the HTML snippet that this script is targetting, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: What if two checkboxes are un-checked, and one is checked? Do you need *all* checkboxes checked (however many there are) or only that at least one is checked?

Comment: It's targetting those inputs, based on the ID.

Comment: I need to return false if all are unchecked, if one is checked I don't need to return false.

Comment: Just check whether it exists: `&& ($('#parrot_pop_'+id+').length && !$('#parrot_pop_'+id+':checked').length)`. Select the element before you make the test (bit cleaner).

Comment: @FelixKling That doesn't help because if I just have two checkboxes and one of them is checked I don't need to return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest grouping the checkboxes together within a common parent:

```
<fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dog_pop_123">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_pop_123">
    <input type="checkbox" id="parrot_pop_123">
</fieldset>
```

And using the following:

```
return !($('#group1 input:checkbox').length == $('#group1 input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length);
```

Effectively if the number of checkboxes is equal to the number of un-checked checkboxes return false (using the `!` operator), else return true.

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Comment: David Thomas this is an excelent approach. However I can't group them because they are in separate parts of the DOM.  And also it can be other checkboxes that I don't want to take into account...

Comment: Then you'd help yourself, and us, if you could show some sample html so we can see what your html looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var id = 123, 
    checkboxes = $('#dog_pop_' + id + ', #cat_pop_' + id + ', #parrot_pop_' + id);
if(checkboxes.filter(function() {return this.checked !== true;}).length !== checkboxes.length) {
    //Not all checkboxes are checked
}
```

Comment: I need to target them with the ID. I can't just look for all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input[id$="pop_123"]').length != $('input[id$="pop_123"]:checked').length ) {
  return false;
}
```

should do the trick unless you have many ids ending in pop_123. In that case, you can add the `[type=checkbox]` filter too.

Using `$=` in the selector means ends with. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)